# Regex for price in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
<input type="text" id="price" />

$('#price').keyup(function(){
        $('#price').val($('#price').val().replace(',', '.'));
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2KRHh/1/

This replaces `,` with `.`. This is OK, but I would like to replace all characters which are not numbers with NULL. How can I do this with a regular expression?

Comment: Why would you add characters (those following the decimal) while the user is still typing? That's really not aiding the user, that's irritating and a hindrance. Add characters/pad the string *after they've finished* (`blur()`).

Comment: @DavidThomas you're right, i edited my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the point of usability, it makes not much sense to guess what the user might have wanted or not and then try to correct those errors. Just use a pattern like following:

```
<input class="" type="text" id="price" pattern="\d+\.\d\d"/>
```

Modern browsers will validate the input field according to the pattern, and you can use `$(this).attr("pattern")` to also validate against it.

Now if it does not match, just prompt the user to kindly correct their input.

In it's simplest form it might look like the [following example](http://jsfiddle.net/2KRHh/2/). It just does a simple replace on the input (,->.) (this might not even be necessary if you use the pattern `"\d+[.,]\d\d"` and correct it afterwards to your liking) and then tries to validate. If it fails, the user cannot commit and is prompted to correct their input.

Comment: As long as you don't care about IE9... Suggestions like this really should always come with disclaimers otherwise people will blindly follow them without realizing where it will / will not work

Comment: What hinders you to use the pattern to manually validate the input in the browsers that don't know how to handle it? Btw. That is what i wrote in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [my jQuery iMask plugin](http://cwolves.github.io/jQuery-iMask/), though what you're asking for specifically:

```
.replace( /.*?(\d+)(?:\.(\d{1,2}))?.*/, function( rx, dollars, cents ){
    cents = +( cents || 0 );
    return (+dollars + (cents/((cents<10)?10:100))).toFixed(2);
} );
```

If you just want to strip non-numeric numbers:

```
.replace( /[^0-9.]/g, '' )
```

Comment: @raam86 -- no, I want to optionally match 2 decimals, not match it a more than once

Comment: Of course. Could you explain a little more about the pattern?

Comment: match any number of decimals, then ( a dot, up to 2 decimals ) -- this piece is optional